# How do I merge changes of a git fork into master of my repo?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I have a repository on Github and someone has forked it and made changes (that have helped improve the repository). Is there a `git` command that will allow me to take those changes made by the other user and modify my original master repo to match that forked repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**option 1: Use GitHub's Pull Request mechanism**

Pull Requests were designed especially for this purpose: making it easier for beginners and non-git experts to accept contributions from forks.

See also:

- [Configuring pull request merges](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges)
- [How to accept a GitHub Pull Request](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ROLLER/How+to+accept+a+GitHub+Pull+Request)

**option 2: setup the forked repo as a remote**

The other option is to setup the fork as an additional remote and fetch/pull from it. But that is more advanced and you sound like a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

To expound on Inigo's answer

For option 2, to setup the forked repo as a remote, you would perform the following git commands at the root of your project directory

```
git remote add forkedrepo https://github.com/xxx/yyy.git
git fetch forkedrepo
git merge forkedrepo/master
```